# Simple encrypting system

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a simple encrypting system. I made a code with all letters but when I write text and click the button to encrypt it just recognizes one letter.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="text">
<input type="button" id="send" onclick="onClick()" value="encript">

<a id="itext">Your text will show here</a>
<a type="text" id="code">Your encrypted text will be showed here</a>
```

JS:

```
function onClick() {

    var txt = document.getElementById("text").value;
    document.getElementById("itext").innerHTML = txt;

    if(txt == "a"){
        document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = "yv";
    }
    if(txt == "b"){
        document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = "eh";
    }
    if(txt == "c"){
        document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = "ps";
    }
...
}
```

Comment: To guide you in the right direction: What you're doing at the moment is checking if the whole text is a single letter. You'd have to check every letter on every position to replace them.

Comment: You could also change see the encryption live without first clicking on the button, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're checking the entirety of the string against single letters. You should split the string into characters and iterate over each of them. Something like this:

```
function onClick() {

    var txt = document.getElementById("text").value;
    document.getElementById("itext").innerHTML = txt;
    var letters = txt.split('')
    var new_string = ''
    var i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
        if(letters[i] == "a"){
            new_string = new_string + "yv";
        }
        if(letters[i] == "b"){
            new_string = new_string + "eh";
        }
        if(letters[i] == "c"){
            new_string = new_string + "ps";
        }
        ...
    }
    document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = new_string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I dont remembered the for cicle you helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could also build a function that catches your keyboard input like this:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
if(event.keyCode == 65) {
  var code = document.getElementById("code");
    code.appendChild(document.createTextNode("yv"));
}
else if(event.keyCode == 66) {
     var code = document.getElementById("code");
     code.appendChild(document.createTextNode("eh"));
}
else if(event.keyCode == 67) {
    var code = document.getElementById("code");
    code.appendChild(document.createTextNode("ps"));
}
```

});

i have made an example here:
https://jsbin.com/bohucecudu/edit?html,output

If you got this, then you don't need to click first on the button to get results :)